# `devtools::test()` works, but `devtools::check()` does not for `system.file` to locate file with `.yml` extension

Tags: r, yaml, devtools

I am trying to locate an external file with `.yml` extension for creating unit test with `testthat` while building a R package, the file is placed under `\inst` folder, as mentioned here https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#data-extdata. Am using `system.file()` to load the file with `yaml` package for some unit test (**not** `base::system.file()`, so that `pkgload:::shim_system.file()` can intercept). The tests passes if I do `devtools::test()`, but it keeps throwing error when I run `devtools::check()`.

However, interestingly after lots of trials I found out that `devtools::check()` does not throw any error if I save the file with `.txt` extension instead of `.yaml`/`.yml`.

```
##   inside test_that()
##   cf <- system.file("config", "config1.yml", package = "mypackage", mustWork = TRUE)

##   Error note after devtools::check()
Error in `system.file("config", "config1.yml", package = "mypackage", mustWork = TRUE)`: no file found
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-base::system.file(...) test-set_config.R:34:2

[ FAIL 1 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 15 ]

# -------------------------------------------------------------

## No error in devtools::check() when config1.yml is renamed as config1.txt !!
```

Anyone experienced the same? Am using latest version of `devtools` as on CRAN (v2.4.2), on R 4.1.1. If yes, is there any way to keep using `.yaml`/`.yml`, and not `.txt`?

**UPDATE**
I did accidentally keep `[.]yml`, `[.]yaml` in `.Rbuildignore` to ignore the continuous integration yaml files, have made them specifc instead of wildcards - and it is working now! Apologies for raising a false alarm, I was myself quite confused when I got this weird thing. https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2384#issuecomment-947943050

Comment: Does this behave any differently if the file is not a yaml file?

Comment: That is what I mentioned in the question, if the same file is saved with .txt extension then it works. YAML package of R can still load it as it does not have to be .yml for yaml::yaml.load_file to work. But it is odd.

Comment: @VivekAtal What is the directory structure under `inst/`?  And what is the filepath to `config1.yml` (relative to the project)?

Comment: directory structure: `inst/config/config1.yml` - there is only one file under `inst/config` folder. If I change the file extension to `.txt`, the new directory structure becomes `inst/config/config1.txt`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I read it completely but somehow missed that clear/salient point. My apologies!

Comment: I cannot replicate this error when I try with a simple new package. The file is found with the `.yml` extension no problem. There is nothing in the shim code that looks at the package extension at all that I can see. Are you sure you have the `package = "mypackage"` set properly? Do you already have the package installed in your `.libPaths()` or is it just in your development folder?

Comment: I did check for preinstalled library in `.libPaths()` earlier, it was not the issue. Finally the culprit was my `.Rbuildignore` - I accidentally keep `[.]yml`, `[.]yaml` in `.Rbuildignore` to ignore the continuous integration yaml files, have made them specifc instead of wildcards - and it is working now! Apologies for raising a false alarm, I was myself quite confused when I got this weird thing. Thanks @jimhester who responded on github https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2384#issuecomment-947943050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, finally, the culprit was my `.Rbuildignore` - I accidentally kept `[.]yml`, `[.]yaml` in `.Rbuildignore` to ignore the continuous integration yaml files while building the package. I modified them and made them specific, instead of wildcards - and it is working now! Apologies for raising a false alarm; I was quite confused when I got this weird thing. Thanks, @jimhester, who responded on [github `devtools` issues](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2384#issuecomment-947943050)